# Exclamation point in bash function name - should I?

Tags: bash, naming

I'm writing a bash script and it's really convenient to use an exclamation point in a function name.

Example:

```bsh
function hello! {
    echo goodbye
}
function hello {
    echo hello
}
```

**And it works!**

After looking through the [specs](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Definitions), I found this:

> ***name***
>       A word consisting solely of letters, numbers, and underscores, and beginning with a letter or underscore. Names are used as shell variable and function names. Also referred to as an identifier.

I feel like I'm breaking the rules here. Is this wrong? Will this mess something up in the future? What's actually going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Out of burning curiousity, why is it so much more convenient to use the exclamation point in your function name?

Generally, for portability reasons, you may not want to use the bang; just because the interpreter on that particular OS accepts it, if you need to deploy that script elsewhere, other interpreters of slightly different flavors/versions may not be as accepting.

Comment: Well the functions I'm writing are wrappers that do a little error checking, so I want them to be short. The wrappers with ! exit on failure, other wrappers just print a warning and don't exit. It makes things very clear.

Comment: That can be accomplished by using "_e"(xits) instead of an "!" as well. No need to use potential compatibility issues/bugs/whatever else thats not in the specs ;)

Answer (score 6):

Since it violates the Bash spec, I'd say you're exploiting a bug in Bash, so your code might not work when the bug is fixed. Drop the `!`

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about the implications in this case, but if the specification states something this clearly, I'd say anything beyond that is undefined behavior and should be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a good idea to use ! in a function name if you want your code to be portable.  bash --posix or invoking bash as "sh" both reject "hello!" as a function name.  But I suspect that bash silently permits aberrant function names ("hello?" "hello-" and "hello/" also work, to name a few) because one important use of functions is allowing the user to override normal commands and these commands (e.g. ls, rm, etc.) can contain any sort of character allowed by the filesystem.

Note that "hello!" as a *variable* name doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If your function is meant to be invoked by an user as a command from the terminal, i. e. it's defined in `.bashrc`, then you could give it a longer name and create an alias with the bang at the end.

Example:

```bash
function cd_mkdir {
    DEST=$1
    mkdir -p "$DEST"
    cd "$DEST"
}

alias cd!=cd_mkdir
```

Now, while in terminal I can invoke this as:

```bash
cd! foo/bar/baz
```

And the `foo`, `bar` and `baz` directories get created if they don't exists.

The exclamation mark at the end is a nice and easy mnemonic of "shouting" the familiar command to be force executed, even if the original variant of the command couldn't.